# Monitor urls using c#

Tags: c#, website-monitoring

I am developing asp.net website for url monitoring. 
I looked around for open source tools and none of them provide restful APIs so that they can be called from my application.
Are there any open source packages that I can directly use?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by URL monitoring? You want to monitor if its up/down or if the page changes?

Comment: Yes. Lets say I have an application server, I would like to check if the server is properly executing. I should be able to send request to the server and check various status messages.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the content of the URLs right?

No service will have a restful API since they will be local packages.

If you want to get the website/service content and check sometime in it, try .Net Frameworks HttpClient or System.Net.WebRequest.

For easier parsing you can use HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 0):

The following posts will help your to solve you problem:

http://aspalliance.com/237_How_to_Check_URLs_Using_NET
http://obout.com/sitemonitoring/sitemonitoring.aspx